# FastReport causes delphi crash

Tags: delphi, fastreport

When I place `frxReport1` on a form, and place a Master band on that, I close `frxReport1` from FastReport designer. When I double click on `frxReport1` again, Delphi crashes and closes.

Some detail:

- when I click on another `frxReport` designed before by me, the crashed doesn't happen and it work normally.
- `frxReport` without Master band works normally too.
- I work and program on my laptop. When I'm in the office, this problem doesn't happen, but when I use the same laptop and same Delphi version, this problem appears.

[image]

***[Edited]***

I simply explain the problem step by step:

Step1: add the components: adoConnection,adoQuery,frxDBDataset,frxReport.

Step2: Build connectionString of adoConnection (to a local accessible database)

Step3: change the Connection property of adoQuery to the adoConnection mentioned in Step2.

Step4: change the DataSet property of frxDBDataset to adoQuery mentioned in Step3.

Step5: Double click on frxReport and add a ReportHeader band, a Header band, and a MasterDetail band.

Step6: From the "Report" menu, choose Data menu and set to frxDBDataset mentioned in  Step4.

Step7: Double click on MasterDetail band and select frxDBDataset.

after the Step7, I close fast report designer and when I double click on frxReport, the error occurs.

You can download the sample project (create on Delphi XE6) from the [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=07835424154862380060)

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the Laptop?

Comment: Yes, I tried right now, but nothing solved.

Comment: I'm using Delphi XE6 but, I create the same project on delphi XE, but the same problem occures for this one, too.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at attached datasource for Master band. Seems that from home you haven't access to the database

Comment: The Database is local and i have full access to that.

Comment: Probably somewhere in a project some folder with design time values referred to network resources. Which version of FastReport have you use? If possible could you please paste content of report?

Comment: Theres no network related part. I use a local database and it's fully accessible. I edited the question and added the part "Edited" to the question above to clarify the problem.

Comment: Can you try to reinstall FastReport components to ensure that you are using same version? Looks like designers itself are crashed - so please check them

Comment: I reinstalled it but the problem is exist. I think it's a matter of windows mis-configuration or such a thing. By the way I changed my windows. Thanks for your ideas.